How can I start the gpg-agent daemon without a user logging on to the system
I am trying to pre-cache a GPG password into gpg-agent on a headless Ubuntu 20.04 server, I would like to achieve this without a user having to log on to the system.
The aim of this pre-caching is to get msmtp to read an email password (using passwordeval) which has been encrypted using GPG, without any interaction from a user.  I understand this provides limited security (the GPG password is stored on the server) but it does prevent the email password being stored on disk in plain-text and means it cannot be accidentally committed into my code repo in plain-text either.
I have written a script which preloads the password and this works well if I login to the server.  However, if I do not login, the gpg-agent is not started by systemd and so the password is not pre-cached.
cache-gpg-agent.sh
#!/bin/bash

export GNUPGHOME=/root/.gnupg

# Load our GPG password
set -o allexport
source /root/.credentials/gpg/.env
set +o allexport

GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY

# Configure gpg-agent
echo allow-preset-passphrase > $GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent.conf
echo default-cache-ttl 34560000 >> $GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent.conf
echo max-cache-ttl 34560000 >> $GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent.conf

# Import GPG key
gpg --batch --import /root/.credentials/my-key.asc

# Loop Keygrips and set password
gpg --fingerprint --with-keygrip my-email@test.com | awk '/Keygrip/ { print $3 }' | xargs -I {} /bin/sh -c 'echo "$GPG_KEY_PASSWORD" | /usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset {}'

unset GPG_KEY_PASSWORD

I then set up a systemd service to run this script on system boot.
cache-gpg-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=Cache GPG Agent
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/myuser/scripts/cache-gpg-agent.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target"

This didn't seem to work, when I logged in to the system I couldn't see a gpg-agent daemon instance.  I tried adding the following to the script to initiate the gpg-agent:
eval $(gpg-agent --homedir /root/.gnupg --daemon)

but this also didn't work (I think the systemd instance of gpg-agent which runs on demand via /usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent.service) replaces this instance I try to create.
I then tried adding a loop to my script to wait for an instance of gpg-agent to start:
while ! pgrep -f "gpg-agent --homedir /root/.gnupg --daemon" > /dev/null; do
    echo "Waiting for gpg-agent to start" >> /tmp/cache-gpg-agent.log
    sleep 1
done

This showed me that none of the GPG commands in my script were initiating the gpg-agent daemon.  As soon as I logged into the system and issued any gpg command, gpg-agent is loaded, my wait condition is satisfied and the password is pre-cached.
So I have the pieces I need but I cannot get gpg-agent to start before a user logs into the system which is the desired goal.
The key seems to be something to do with the gpg-agent services installed in /usr/lib/systemd/user/ which are run on-demand by any gpg commands, but these are run in the user context and I need them to run in the system context I think.
I've tried creating duplicates of the user services and added them to the services context but this was unsuccessful too - I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to systemd .
Does anyone know if this can be achieved, I'm failing to understand why my script doesn't work, even when I load gpg-agent --daemon directly in my script - it seems any connectivity with gpg-agent can only occur once a user is logged in - is this a limitation I cannot work around?
Update
Thanks to information provided by u1686_grawity I managed to get this to work using the following steps:
I enabled service lingering for my root user as suggested:
loginctl enable-linger root
I also relocated my service file to the recommended location and updated the After and WantedBy attributes:
/root/.config/systemd/user/cache-gpg-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=Cache GPG Agent
After=sockets.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/myuser/scripts/cache-gpg-agent.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target

Finally, I updated the permissions, enabled the new service and rebooted.
chmod 600 /root/.config/systemd/user/cache-gpg-agent.service
systemctl --user enable cache-gpg-agent
This has allowed any background scripts on my system to decrypt GPG encrypted files without me having to log in to the system at boot, which is what I was trying to achieve.

For systemd services in 'user' context, loginctl enable-linger <user> will set the flag that will cause that user's service manager to start on boot and persist until shutdown.
Even with that in place, though, you should still pay attention to service dependencies and ordering. There is no guarantee that your script will start at a point where 'user' services are already up; your .service needs an explicit dependency on user@0.service to ensure that.
It might be easier to make your .service also run in user context (via /root/.config/systemd/user/), as then it will naturally start only when root's user service manager starts. (It will automatically be ordered after all user-context .socket units, so it can rely on gpg-agent "on demand" startup.)

Another note: GnuPG previously overdid its systemd integration a bit, so now they've pulled back to the other extreme and completely removed support for having systemd start gpg-agent – though some distributions patch it back in. Without that, though, my understanding of the new situation is that gpg-agent is now always started "on demand" by gpg (where previously it was started by systemd whenever gpg attempted to contact it).
(This means that the gpg-agent process now becomes part of your systemd .service – and therefore, as soon as your service exits, the "leftover" gpg-agent process will be killed as well.)
